# Remove object from array of object if all the property of an object is empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects, where each object has certain properties. I want to remove those objects from the array which have empty strings assigned for all properties within the object.

Example :

```
var x = [{
   "userName" : "XYZ",
   "age": 22,
   "gender": "M"
}, {
   "userName" : "ABC",
   "age": 23,
   "gender": "M"
}, {
   "userName" : "Mohan",
   "age":"",
   "gender": ""
}, {
   "userName" : "",
   "age":"",
   "gender": ""
}]
```

Result should be

```
[{
   "userName" : "XYZ",
   "age": 22,
   "gender": "M"
}, {
   "userName" : "ABC",
   "age": 23,
   "gender": "M"
}, {
   "userName" : "Mohan",
   "age":"",
   "gender": ""
}]
```

Comment: `"age":"gender": ""` is invalid syntax. have you made any attempt at all yourself yet? Please post the code you've tried

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes tried.

Comment: @PremBhushanKarn if you had tried, kindly add the code snippet you have tried with a description on what did not work out to your question post

Comment: Please add in your code that you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `filter`, `every` and `Object.values`:

```js
const x = [{
   "userName" : "XYZ",
   "age": 22,
   "gender": "M"
}, {
   "userName" : "ABC",
   "age": 23,
   "gender": "M"
}, {
   "userName" : "Mohan",
   "age":"",
   "gender": ""
}, {
   "userName" : "",
   "age":"",
   "gender": ""
}]

const y = x.filter(z => !Object.values(z).every(w => w ===""))

console.log(y)
```

Comment: perfect answer.